# How to mock a call to an exe file with Pester?

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, mocking, pester

Developing a script in PowerShell, I require to call an external executable file(.exe). currently I am developing this script with a TDD approach, therefore I require to mock the called to this .exe file.

I try this :

```
Describe "Create-NewObject" {
    Context "Create-Object" {
        It "Runs" {
            Mock '& "c:\temp\my.exe"' {return {$true}}
            Create-Object| Should Be  $true
        }
    }
}
```

I got this response:

```
Describing Create-NewObject
   Context Create-Object
    [-] Runs 574ms
      CommandNotFoundException: Could not find Command & "C:\temp\my.exe"
      at Validate-Command, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 801
      at Mock, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\Functions\Mock.ps1: line 168
      at <ScriptBlock>, C:\T\Create-NewObject.tests.ps1: line 13
Tests completed in 574ms
Passed: 0 Failed: 1 Skipped: 0 Pending: 0 Inconclusive: 0
```

Is there a way to mock this kind of calls without encapsulate them inside a function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a way to mock the call to this executable files:

```
function Create-Object
{
   $exp = '& "C:\temp\my.exe"'
   Invoke-Expression -Command $exp
}
```

And the test with the mock should looks like:

```
Describe "Create-NewObject" {
    Context "Create-Object" {
        It "Runs" {
            Mock Invoke-Expression {return {$true}} -ParameterFilter {($Command -eq '& "C:\temp\my.exe"')
            Create-Object| Should Be  $true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best option that I've come up with as well, but I believe `Invoke-Experssion` is considered a 'code smell'.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, unfortunately, as of Pester 4.8.1:

- you *cannot* mock *external executables* by their *full paths* (e.g, `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`)
- you *can* mock them by *file name only* (e.g., `cmd`), but beware that in older Pester versions the mock is only called for invocations that explicitly use the `.exe` extension (e.g., `cmd.exe`) - see [this (obsolete) GitHub issue](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/1043)

[Your own workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37927372/45375) is effective, but it involves `Invoke-Expression`, which is awkward; [`Invoke-Expression` should generally be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)

Here's a workaround that uses a helper function, `Invoke-External`, which *wraps* the invocation of external programs and, as a *function*, can itself be mocked, using a `-ParameterFilter` to filter by executable path:

In your code, define the `Invoke-External` function and then use it to make your call to `c:\temp\my.exe`:

```
# Helper function for invoking an external utility (executable).
# The raison d'être for this function is to allow 
# calls to external executables via their *full paths* to be mocked in Pester.
function Invoke-External {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $LiteralPath,
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
    $PassThruArgs
  )
  & $LiteralPath $PassThruArgs
}

# Call c:\temp\my.exe via invoke-External
# Note that you may pass arguments to pass the executable as usual (none here):
Invoke-External c:\temp\my.exe
```

Then, to mock the call to `c:\temp\my.exe` in your Pester tests:

```
Mock Invoke-External -ParameterFilter { $LiteralPath -eq 'c:\temp\my.exe' } `
  -MockWith { $true }
```

Note: If you only have *one* call to an external executable in your code, you can omit the 
`-ParameterFilter` argument.

Comment: I think, in your `Invoke-External` function you should use parameter splatting and replace `& $LiteralPath $PassThruArgs` with `& $LiteralPath @PassThruArgs` to correctly handle native command arguments

Comment: @GrzegorzWolszczak, while you may choose to use `@` for conceptual clarity, it isn't necessary: when calling _external programs_, passing an array as an argument _implicitly_ results in [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), i.e the array's elements are passed as individual arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something this and seemed to work.

```
$PathToExe = 'C:\Windows\System32\wevtutil.exe'
New-Item -Path function: -Name $PathToExe -Value { ... }
Mock $PathToExe { ... }
```